# mssql_query(): message: Incorrect syntax near ''(severity 15)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, left-join

when I run my code i get this error:

> Warning: mssql_query(): message: Incorrect syntax near 'bstplanning'.
> (severity 15) in /var/www/bstplanning/report/scorecard2.php on line 91
>
> Warning: mssql_query(): General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server (severity 15) in
> /var/www/bstplanning/report/scorecard2.php on line 91

My code looks like this:

```
    if ($team != 'All') {
    $sql_team = "users.split = '" . $team . "' AND";
    $sql_user = "users.user_id LIKE '%'";
} else {
    $sql_team = "users.user_id LIKE '%' AND";
    if ($user != 'All') {
        $sql_user = "users.user_id = '" . $user . "'";
    } else {
        $sql_user = "users.user_id LIKE '%'";
    }
}

$sql = "
SELECT 
        Drive.Owner 
        ,ROUND(AVG(CAST(actual AS FLOAT)), 2) as rezult
        ,ROUND(Sum(CAST(Ontime AS FLOAT))/Sum(task_count), 2) as rezult2
       ,ROUND(sum(case when firsta != 'none' then 1 else 0 end)/ROUND(CAST(count(firsta)AS FLOAT),2)*100,2) nones1
       ,ROUND(sum(case when seconda != 'none' then 1 else 0 end)/ROUND(CAST(count(seconda)AS FLOAT),2)*100,2) nones1
       ,ROUND(CAST(count(dock )AS FLOAT),2)/CAST(sum(case when dock = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)AS FLOAT)*100 as documentavail
       ,(sum(case when dock = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)+sum(case when dock = 'old' then 1 else 0 end))/count(dock)*100 as documentavail
FROM (
SELECT 
    users.user_name+ ' ' +users.user_surname AS Owner
    ,users.split as test
    ,sc.firstbackup as firsta
    ,sc.secondbackup as seconda
    ,sc.documentation as dock
    ,sc.active as active
    ,(SELECT CASE WHEN non_sc = '1' THEN 'regular' ELSE 'sc' END) as sc_or_non_sc
    FROM
    sc

INNER JOIN
    users
ON sc.user_id = users.user_id

WHERE
     " . $sql_team . "  " . $sql_user . "
) Drive
left join
(
SELECT
     bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.track
    ,bstplanning.dbo.users.split
    ,bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.country
    ,bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.client
    ,bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.task_group
    ,MAX(ISNULL(bstplanning.dbo.users.user_name,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(bstplanning.dbo.users.user_surname,'')) as Owner
    ,AVG(CASE WHEN bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.ontime = 'on time' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END)*COUNT(bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.country) AS Ontime
    ,AVG(CASE WHEN bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.accuracy = 'accurate' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS actual
    ,COUNT(bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.country) AS task_count

FROM 
    bstplanning.dbo.sc_data 

INNER JOIN bstplanning.dbo.users 
    ON bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.user_id = bstplanning.dbo.users.user_id  

WHERE
    bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.date >= '" . $nuo . "' AND bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.date <= '" . $iki . "' AND  " . $sql_team . " " . $sql_user . " bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.actual > 0 AND
    ((bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.ontime='on time' OR bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.ontime = 'late') OR (bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.accuracy='accurate' OR bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.accuracy = 'error'))
    
GROUP BY
     bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.country
    ,bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.client
    ,bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.task_group
    ,bstplanning.dbo.users.split
    ,bstplanning.dbo.sc_data.track
    ) Drive2
    on Drive.Owner=Drive2.Owner
    where sc_or_non_sc ='sc'
    group by
        Drive.Owner
";
```

I don't know whats wrong because when i run code in SQL Server Management it works fine. I think problem is with $team or $user, but i cant figure how to fix it. This is crazy, when i remove "Where" from select it works.

Comment: Did you check the outcome of `$sql` and ran that in Management Studio? Best way to find out is to output `$sql` when it has filled in all variables, etc. because right now there is no way of knowing what line 91 is or where the error is and it is basically a needle in the haystack.

Comment: "when i run code in SQL Server Management it works fine" - it seems to be an SQL syntax error. Maybe, you missed something, while debugging. Are you sure, that you ran exactly the SQL, that is being executed in php?

Comment: sorry for not adding 91 line, 91 line contains "$result = mssql_query ($sql);"

Comment: @user4035 I don't think so, I copied text many times, tried to change variables but it seem that something doesn't want to work. I think that problem might be with left join, because they are two different tables.

Comment: Just before executing like 91, the actual query execution, add an `echo sql;` and post the query.

Comment: @Macb3th Did you print the actual SQL, before running it with mssql_query(), and it works fine in Management Studio?

Comment: @ConradLotz http://prntscr.com/79w2es this is what i get back.

Comment: @user4035 yes my query work fine in Studio. But when i put in php something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong. I'm not sure why, but when i removed $team, $user from left join where condition it worked.